# xamarin forms carousel view swipe over button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am newbie to xamarin.I came across a problem where I need to have carousel view without swipe and it should only done by button (next and back button) anyone know how to do it ? is there any property to disable the swiping ?

Comment: You can set selected page programmatically. if you want to disable swipe you should not use carousel

Comment: rather having carousel do you mean can I use normal xamarin form to achieve this ?

Comment: if you don't let the user to use swipe then use normal windows

Comment: I have started to doing so let you know the progress